# Stripe checkout working on local machine but not on test server- for test mode only

Tags: stripe-payments

In **.env file** : I have assigned variables for ***stripe API Publishable key and Secret key* of test data.**

I am able to checkout on my local machine using the .env file variable.

> 200 OK POST   /v1/charges
>
> 200 OK POST   /v1/tokens

But when I am using the same key variable on test server, it is not working and gives me error as shown below:

```
 You did not set a valid 
 publishable key. Call 
 Stripe.setPublishableKey() 
 with your publishable key.
 For more info, see 
 https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js
```

> 400 ERR OK POST   /v1/charges
>
> 200 OK POST      /v1/tokens

Below are my files

.web  (/home/p1/projectName/.envs_template/.development/.web)

```
STRIPE_API_KEY=pk_test_xxxxxxxxx
```

File1.js
(/home/p1/projectName/ac/client/app/component/f1/f2/File1.js)

```
//injecting value of test data publishable key(pk_test_xxxxxxxxx) from .env file
const STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE = process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY;

<StripeCheckout
    amount={convertUSDtoCent(value)}
    token={(token) => dispatch(subscribeplan(token, *, *, *, *, *, value))}
    currency={CURRENCY}
    stripeKey={STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE}
    >
    <button id="1" className=' checkout action-btn'> <FormattedMessage id="MDB.MUM.Checkout" defaultMessage="Checkout"/> </button>
</StripeCheckout>
```

Comment: Hi  , Can you try logging the publishable key variable in JavaScript on your test server to ensure you are loading the right value?  Can you share the code where you are loading values from your `.env` file?  Please provide more details about your implementation in order to ensure you get good responses.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem. @harry how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was that the publishable key was not getting fetched from the `.env` file,which should reflect here as shown in the image below:

[image]

For the key to be reflected in the image shared, I used the `genClientConfig.js` file

```
const CC_STRIPE_API_KEY = process.env.CC_STRIPE_API_KEY;

"stripe_key":CC_STRIPE_API_KEY
```

And used "stripe_key" in below file as:

```
stripeKey={ClientConfig.stripe_key}
```

File1.js (/home/p1/projectName/ac/client/app/component/f1/f2/File1.js)

```
<StripeCheckout
    amount={convertUSDtoCent(value)}
    token={(token) => dispatch(subscribeplan(token, *, *, *, *, *, value))}
    currency={CURRENCY}
    stripeKey={ClientConfig.stripe_key}
    >
    <button id="1" className=' checkout action-btn'> <FormattedMessage id="MDB.MUM.Checkout" defaultMessage="Checkout"/> </button>
</StripeCheckout>
```